# Prevent script crash on permissions error

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have written a script for backing up files. However I just encountered an issue. It'll rarely be a problem but in the case that it is I want to prevent abnormal behaviour.

the script checks the files in one directory and then checks in another, any that exist in the first but not in the 2nd are copied over, therefore backing them up.

However I just tried it with one of the files to copy opened in excel, the script returned the error:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\dev\\DailyStatistics\\September\\~$Update Rates 050914.xlsx'
```

I expect that's because it was open at the time.

How can I modify my script so that if this happens it calls this command:

```
print "One or more of the files you tried to backup were open. Please save and close the document and try again"
```

This is the part of the script that copies the files:

```
for file in source_files:
filename = file[-11:-1]
year = filename[-6:-4]
foldername = directory_mapping[filename[-8:-6]]
if not os.path.exists("W://20" + year + '/' + foldername + "/"):
    os.makedirs("W://20" + year + '/' + foldername + '/')
if filename not in bfiles:
    shutil.copy(file, 'W://20' + year + '/' + foldername + '/')
    files_transferred = files_transferred + 1
```

***EDIT:***

John Zwinck's answer below does indeed work. However I looked a bit deeper into the problem and realised that whilst the error is being raise, the file is actually transferred.

I deleted all files from the backup location and then opened up 2 source files to test the try/except block.

The except worked and I got the 2 error messages, but before closing the documents and trying again I check the destination file and both files are there with correct size.

Why is python throwing this error if the files are actually transferring correctly.

***UPDATE:***

The reason for the problem described above was because of the way windows was locking the file. Excel creates a hidden file when it has something open. Because this file also matched the pattern it was trying to copy that too.

The error was being thrown on the hidden "temp" file rather than the actual open file.

In order to get around this I changed my matching method.

It now only matches files that end with `.xlsx` and do not begin with `~$`. That fixed the problem as it now ignores hidden files!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try:
    shutil.copy(file, 'W://20' + year + '/' + foldername + '/')
except IOError as ex:
    print ex, "Please save and close the document and try again"
```

Comment: This works great, but I've noticed something else. Please see edit, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Use a try-except block:

```
try:
    shutil.copy(file, 'W://20' + year + '/' + foldername + '/')
except IOError:
    print "One or more of the files you tried to backup were open. Please save and close the document and try again"
```